# Facebook: Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data thrown

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post photo from my server to Facebook, but I get strange error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data thrown in base_facebook.php on line 886

And app code is here:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$file =  "/uploads/test_photo.jpg";
$post_data = array(
    "message" => "My photo caption",
    "source" => '@' . realpath($file)
);
$album_id = "10150639478245912";
$data = $facebook->api("/".$album_id."/photos", 'post', $post_data); 
print_r($data);
```

Permission which app use:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
  array('scope' => 'publish_stream, user_photos')
);
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer, but it might be where the CURL is transforming the image from a file location to a byte stream for the multipart posting.  Maybe the webserver/CURL doesn't have access to get the data bytes of the $file you specified?

Answer (score 1):

check the file if it have been really uploaded... sometimes the file url is empty because nothing was uploaded and that results in getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this...

```
$post_data = array(
  "message" => "My photo caption",
  "source" => '@' . realpath($file)
);
```

try this...

```
$post_data = array(
  "message" => "My photo caption"
) 
$post_data[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
```

Comment: The API would be expecting the file to be in the `source` variable and servers do not determine uploaded files' names that way.